# How can I display a number to represent the order of post?

Tags: query

I want to display the numerical number next to the_title of my WordPress posts. For example, I have 10 posts already:

- 001 - First Post
- 002 - Second Post
  ...
- 010 - So on...

I have tried it with a a number that adds '1++' in every loop but what it displays is the opposite: First post = "010", Last post = "001".

here's my code. I want the reverse of this:

```
<?php 
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type'   => 'projects',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));

$start_value = 000;

if (have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'skill');

$start_value++;
$counter = sprintf("%03s",$start_value);

?>

<?php

echo $counter; include(locate_template('home/format.php'));
// displays as: 001 - This is the Last Post
endwhile; endif;
 ?>
```

Comment: You should [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/181985/edit) and post your code here.

Comment: I tried you code and it's working fine. Unless you are not doing something additional to change the order, it should work fine. Why don't you try removing `include` from your code and directly print post title `echo the_title();` and check.

Comment: `if ( have_posts() )` should be `if ( $query->have_posts() )`. Add `'suppress_filters' => true,` to your query arguments. This will make sure that your query is not altered by filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global `$wp_query` (in this case its the `$query` var) holds the `$current_post` which is available in the loop and tells the index of the current post ( `$wp_query->current_post` ). The `$wp_query->post_count` tells the number of posts being displayed in the loop, and this actually becomes a simple arithmetic solution that will work no matter how many posts the loop shows:

```
if (have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    // code
    $counter = $query->post_count - $query->current_post + 1;
    // code
endwhile; endif;
```

Give it a try and please feedback this if it works for you.

Comment: oh this one works!

Comment: But I found that adding "-1" is much more accurate as I only have 10 posts but the last one counts as "11". so I ended up with this code: `$counter = $query->post_count - $query->current_post + 1 -1;`